# Google Fit get records with history (updates)

Tags: cordova-plugins, google-fit

Is it possible to get the DataPoints with history like last update date/creation data and original/updated value?

I need to get a user's weights, and sync them with my app, but, I need to know what records have been updated after I made the first get for a specific period (like last 01.01.2020 - 02.02.2020).

My app uses ionic and cordova with the health plugin, but that is not the point of my question. If needed I can write a new plugin to acces the fit data.

This is the existing plugin code to get the data: https://github.com/dariosalvi78/cordova-plugin-health/blob/master/src/android/HealthPlugin.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you cannot get the history of the records.